# Data saved correctly using fprintf but prints out weird values

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fopen

I've created a struct:

```
typedef struct aeroplane
{
  int seat;
  char rsv[10];
  char fName[20];
  char lName[20];
} AERO;
```

And created an array in a main function then initialise it:

```
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 4

AERO arr[ROWS][COLS] =
  {
    {
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"}
    },
    {
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"}
    },
    {
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"},
      {0, "Empty", "NULL", "NULL"}
    }
  };
```

I used this function to save the array to `test.dat`:

```
void save(AERO * arr, FILE * fp)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
      fprintf(fp, "%d %s %s %s\n",
      ((arr + i) + j) -> seat, ((arr + i) + j) -> rsv, ((arr + i) + j) -> fName, ((arr + i) + j) -> lName);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }
}
```

And here is what `test.dat` shows:

```
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL

0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL

0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
0 Empty NULL NULL
```

which looks like what I intended.

However, when I used this function to retrieve the data:

```
void read(AERO * arr, FILE * fp)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
      fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s",
      &((arr + i) + j) -> seat, ((arr + i) + j) -> rsv, ((arr + i) + j) -> fName, ((arr + i) + j) -> lName);
    }
  }
}
```

then prints it out:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
      printf("dummy[%d][%d]\nseat = %d\nrsv = %s\nfName = %s\nlName = %s\n\n",
      i, j, dummy[i][j].seat, dummy[i][j].rsv, dummy[i][j].fName, dummy[i][j].lName);
    }
  }
```

The output is not what I intended:

```
dummy[0][0]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[0][1]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[0][2]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[0][3]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[1][0]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[1][1]
seat = 0
rsv = Empty
fName = NULL
lName = NULL

dummy[1][2]
seat = 0
rsv =
fName =
lName = ▒▒

dummy[1][3]
seat = -2144188312
rsv =
fName =
lName =

dummy[2][0]
seat = 0
rsv =
fName =
lName =

dummy[2][1]
seat = 970037024
rsv = ▒
fName =
lName = ▒

dummy[2][2]
seat = -14080
rsv =
fName =
lName =

dummy[2][3]
seat = 31
rsv =
fName =
lName =
```

I expected the output to have 3 rows and 4 columns as I already defined. But it not only returns smaller values but corrupted ones as well. Did I miss something?

Comment: `AERO[ROWS][COLS]` is not compatible with `AERO*`. Turn on your compiler warnings and **mind the warnings**.

Comment: Please read about this: [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will edit it more concisely. Thank you.

Comment: @pmg OH, I just realised how ridiculous the problem is. The only problem was the functions taking pointer as parameters.

Comment: the function: `read()` is a well known C library function. Best to not use c library function names for your function names.  Suggest using something 'active', like `getSeatInfo()`

Comment: @SergeBallesta I enclosed NULL in double quotes, so isn't it considered as a string?

Answer (score 0):

`AERO[ROWS][COLS]` is not compatible with `AERO*`. Turn on your compiler warnings and **mind the warnings**.
                    – pmg